# How to start with post number x?

Tags: posts, wp-query, customization, query, recent-posts

I have two areas where I fetch the most recent entries. In the first area, I want to get the first 10 posts. In the second area, I want to fetch the posts starting at post number 11....

I have this:

```
<?php

$args = array( 'numberposts' => '10' );
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts($args);
$featured_posts = themename_get_featured_posts();
if(!empty($featured_posts) && is_array($featured_posts))
{
    $query_arr = array(
        'post__not_in' => $featured_posts, $recent_posts,
        'paged' => $paged,
        'suppress_filters' => false,
    );
    query_posts($query_arr);
}

$key = 11;
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
    $image_thumb = '';
    $key++;
    $image_id = get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID());
?>
```

But whatever I do (even if I'd remove the first if statement) I keep seeing the same posts in every area...

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it myself. What I did, is adding this:

```php
$loop = new WP_Query(array(
    'offset' => 20,   
));
```

And then changing:

```
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

into:

```
if ($loop->have_posts() ) : while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [pagination parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#pagination-parameters) I see two possibilities: Either use `offset` or `paged`.

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'offset' => 10,
);
```

should work just as well as

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
    'paged' => 2,
);
```

Comment: Nope. I also don't see how that should work. I don't need pagination.... I just want to start with post number 11, without pagination or so. It doesn't work. Behaviour stays the exact same.

Comment: Only because you don't actually display different pages, does not mean you do not want pagination. Because it is exactly what you want ;) This is the standard way, you would go about this. Can you edit (in your question), how you used this in your code?